# Custom title bar issue - soft keyboard moving it

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using a custom title bar, which is set to this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/actionbar_compat"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

My activity's layout is the following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<Button android:id="@+id/toggle_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:text="@string/toggle_title" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logoView"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="50dip"
    android:paddingRight="50dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
    >


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/loginUser"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:inputType="text|textEmailAddress" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/loginPassword"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/loginUser"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/loginPassword"
        android:text="login" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/registerButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/loginButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/loginPassword"
        android:text="register" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I touch the password field, the soft keyboard appears and moves everything to the top, to make it fit while still be able to see the text box that I'm editing. The problem is that it's also moving the title bar and makes it partially invisible.

How can I prevent the title bar from moving in this case?

Answer (score 0):

write on your menifest file  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"